# Apache and tomcat communication in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am running two pods for apache and 4 pods for Tomcat(both pods are running in the same namespace). I expose(services) the apache and tomcat port(80,8080) to outside the world.
When I try to call the apache URL the request is not reaching the tomcat pod.

When I check the modjk log I am seeing the tomcat is not up and not running the correct port.
I am using the mod_jk for apache to tomcat communication.
I have given my worker. property file and Jkmount file here. When I directly access the tomcat the application is working fine, I am new to the Kubernetes.

```
Worker.properties:
worker.list=tomcat,loadbalancer
worker.tomcat.type=ajp13
#worker.myserver.host=127.0.0.1
worker.tomcat.port=8009
worker.tomcat.lbfactor=1
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb

worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcat
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

JK mount:
JkMount /Userinfo/* tomcat

httpd.conf:
JkWorkersFile /opt/apache/conf/worker.properties
Include /opt/apache/conf/jkmount.conf
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
Tomcat AJP:
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
Message:
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (817): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1068): (tomcat) Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=111)
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1728): (tomcat) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2778): (tomcat) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2799): (tomcat) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=1, client_errors=0).
[Tue Dec 08 17:52:54.811 2020] [7:140256921777920] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2995): Service error=-3 for worker=tomcat
```

Comment: From the Kubernetes perspective if the `Apache` and `Tomcat` are placed in separate `Pods` you should communicate between them via network with [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Could you show the `YAML` definitions that you used?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have given my service details.
```Port expose:
kubectl expose deployment apache-tomcat-demo --type=NodePort --name=oapache -n apache-tomcat --port=80 --target-port=80
kubectl expose deployment apache-tomcat-demo --type=NodePort --name=otomcat -n apache-tomcat --port=8080 --target-port=8080
[root# kubectl get svc -n apache-tomcat
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
oapache   NodePort   10.111.184.22    <none>        80:30366/TCP     40h
otomcat   NodePort   10.107.156.132   <none>        8080:30358/TCP   40h``

Comment: I expose the Tomcat AJP port after  got the IP(Nodeport ip and cluster ip) I used that ip and ajp port on my apache worker.properties even it's not working, I tried cluster ip and Node port both i am getting the connection refused.
NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                AGE
ajptomcat   NodePort   xxxxxxxx                 <none>          8009:30915/TCP    3h28m
ajptomcat   ClusterIP   xxxxxxxx                  <none>           8009/TCP              8s

Comment: I exposed the Tomcat 8080 port and used the proxy pass now my apache pod is talking with Tomcat pod, Thanks to all.